# Automate awk getline user input variable asignment (zsh)

Tags: awk

Is it possible to automate the input process for awk getline?

I user an awk script to perform calculations on files, cycling through numerous files at once. The script asks for a number which is used in calculations for the current file.

`BEGIN { t="/dev/tty";printf "Enter number: ">t;getline<t;user_input=$1 }`

Is it possible to automate the "user input" part without changing the script?

I have tried `yes 1 | script` and `printf '1\n1\n...' | script` without luck, the prompt remains and execution does not move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Don't tell it NOT to read from stdin:

```
$ echo 7 | awk 'BEGIN { t="/dev/tty";printf "Enter number: ">t;getline<t;user_input=$1; print user_input }'
Enter number:

$ echo 7 | awk 'BEGIN { printf "Enter number: ";getline;user_input=$1; print user_input }'
Enter number: 7
$
```

You should probably be sending the prompt to stderr though instead of stdout so it doesn't get mixed in with whatever output your script produces:

```
echo 7 | awk 'BEGIN { printf "Enter number: " >"/dev/stderr"; getline;user_input=$1; print user_input }'
Enter number: 7
```

Please do read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to learn when/how to use getline correctly though if you're considering doing so.

I suspect your script should really look more like:

```
BEGIN {
    while ( user_input == "" ) {
        printf "Enter number: " > "/dev/stderr"
        if ( (getline line) > 0 ) {
            user_input = line
        }
    }
    print user_input
}
```

so it won't assume it got input on  the first prompt and you can call it as

```
awk -v user_input=7 '...'
```

if/when you want to skip the user input prompt/response all together and use a predefined value.

You should actually consider not doing that prompt/response in awk at all and do it in shell - that'd be much more appropriate with having each tool do what it does best:

```
user_input=""
while [[ -z "$user_input" ]]; do
    printf 'Enter input: ' >&2
    IFS= read -r user_input
done &&
awk -v user_input="$user_input" 'BEGIN{print user_input} ...'
```

Comment: Thank your for the input. Yes, not telling it to NOT to read from stdin seems like a smart idea. Hm, I was hoping not having to rewrite the thing though it seems that I might be better of revising it anyway. So the quick fix seems like the stderr one and then I have to take a careful look at that old workhorse at some point in time.